# Unable to use Accept Command in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

The command prompt doesn't allow me to key in values. How should I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL*Plus [ACCEPT command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm#BACGJIHF) accepts values from the user using SQL*Plus formats. To declare something as a CHAR(7) you would use `a7` or to declare something as a NUMBER(4,0) you would use `9999`.

```
SQL> accept stdnum char format 'a7' prompt 'Enter student number: '
Enter student number: abc
SQL> accept year number format '9999' prompt 'Enter year: '
Enter year: 2017
```

The documentation defines the syntax (I've shortened it slightly) as:

```
ACCEPT variable [data type] [FORMAT format] [DEFAULT default] [PROMPT text|NOPROMPT] [HIDE]
```